# jQuery DataTables: hide 'delete' button for the last row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a `DataTable` which can return multiple pages in some cases. Each row returned, displays a delete button but what I need it to hide this button on the very last row returned, whether 1 pg or multiple so CSS can't be used in this.

I'd like to learn how to implement this, as `DataTables` are new to me.

Below is my current code I have which is working fine, except for the hiding of the button:

```
// Existing rule datatable creator
var existingRuleTable = $('#existingRulesDataTable')
.on( 'error.dt', function () {
    $('#todrexitingrules').hide();
    $('#errorModal').modal('show');
    $('#errorModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#errorModalCloseButton').focus();
    })
    $('#existingRuleError').html(
                    '<p>There was an issue retrieving the data. Please try again.</p>'
                +   '<p>If the error keeps occurring, please get in touch.</p>');
})
.DataTable({
    "ordering": false,                                                  // Allows ordering
    "searching": false,                                                 // Searchbox
    "paging": true,                                                     // Pagination
    "info": false,                                                      // Shows 'Showing X of X' information
    "pagingType": 'simple_numbers',                                     // Shows Previous, page numbers & next buttons only
    "pageLength": 10,                                                   // Defaults number of rows to display in table. If changing this value change the show/hide below
    "dom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',                           // Positions table elements
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],              // Sets up the amount of records to display
    "fnDrawCallback": function () {
        if ($('#existingRulesDataTable').DataTable().rows().count() < 11) {
            $("div[class='bottom']").hide();                            // Hides paginator & dropdown if less than 11 records returned
        } else {
            $("div[class='bottom']").show();                            // Shows paginator & dropdown if 11 or more records are returned
        }
    },
    'ajax': {
        "type": 'GET',
        "url": "js/dataTable.json",                                     // TODO > Needs to be changed when actual file resolved
        "data": function (data) {
            return data;
        },
        "dataSrc": function(res){
            existingRuleTableCount = res.data.length;
            return res.data;
        }
    },
    "columns": [                                                        // Display JSON data in table
        { "data": "position" },
        { "data": "startTime" },
        { "data": "endTime" },
        { "data": "selectedDays" },
        { "data": "selectedDates" },
        { "data": "selectedMonths" },
        { "data": "timeRange" },
        {
            "data": null,
            "render": function (data) {
                if (buttonclicked == 'Modify') {                        // Displays the radio button when 'Mod' clicked
                    return  '<label class="c-radio" style="margin-bottom: 0px">'
                        +   '<input type="radio" name="existingRuleActionRadioButton" value="option1">'
                        +       '<span class="fa fa-check"></span>'
                        +   '</label>';
                } else if (buttonclicked == 'Delete') {                 // Displays the delete button when 'Del' clicked
                    return '<button name="deleteRuleButton" class="btn btn-danger" id="' + data.position + '">'
                        + '<i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="font-size: large"></i>'
                        + '</button>';
                } else {
                    return ''; // Needed for the 'Add' button click
                }
            }
        },
    ],
    "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
        if (data.startTime == 'Anytime') {
            $('td:eq(1)', row).attr('colspan', 2).css('text-align', 'center').html('All day');  // Adds COLSPAN attribute, centers the wording and changes it from 'Anytime'
            $('td:eq(2)', row).css('display', 'none');                                          // Hides cell next to the cell with COLSPAN attribute
        }

        if (data.timeRange == '-w') {
            $('td:eq(6)', row).html('Working hours');          // Changes text returned by JSON if '-w'
        } else if (data.timeRange == '-oo') {
            $('td:eq(6)', row).html('Out of office hours');    // Changes text returned by JSON if '-oo'
        }
    },
    "destroy": true,
});
```

I have tried the below but not too sure where to add it, so I tried adding this to the `createdRow` section but it didn't work

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function ( oSettings ) {
    return {
        "iStart":         oSettings._iDisplayStart,
        "iEnd":           oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
        "iLength":        oSettings._iDisplayLength,
        "iTotal":         oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
        "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
        "iPage":          Math.ceil( oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength ),
        "iTotalPages":    Math.ceil( oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength )
    };
}

$.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    "fncheckPage": function() {
        var Page = this.fnPagingInfo().iPage;
        if ((+Page + +1) == this.fnPagingInfo().iTotalPages)
        $('#existingRulesDataTable tr:last').find("[name='deleteRuleButton']").hide();
    }
});
```

Whether the data returns 1 or 100 records, I need the last `button` to be removed.  The screen below shows that there are 2pg's which I need the `button` hiding on pg 2 in the last `row` BUT displayed for the last `row` on the first page hence why CSS won't work for me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I recommend not to hide 'delete' button, when you got the last entry in your table (which will look awkward, from user standpoint), but rather to disable that?

Here's the example of my point (I'm sure, you'll grasp the idea):

```js
//table data
const srcData = [
  {name: 'apple', category: 'fruit'},
  {name: 'banana', category: 'fruit'},
  {name: 'carrot', category: 'vegie'},
  {name: 'pineapple', category: 'fruit'},
  {name: 'kiwi', category: 'fruit'},
];
//table initialization
const dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  sDom: 'tp',
  data: srcData,
  ordering: false,
  pageLength:3,
  drawCallback: () => {
    const table = $('#mytable').DataTable();
    $(table.row(table.rows(':last')).node()).find('button').remove();
  },
  columns: [
    {title: 'Name', data: 'name'},
    {
      title: 'Category', 
      data: 'category', 
      render: data => data+'<button class="del">x</button>'},
  ]
});
//'delete' button callback
$('#mytable').on('click', 'td button', function(){
  dataTable.row($(this).closest('tr')).remove().draw();
});
```

```css
tbody td button {float:right}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply however, i need this button to permanently to be hidden/disabled as the user is NOT allowed to modify or delete this row whether there is 1 record or 100 record's.  I get your answer but doesnt work in my scenario as if more than 1 record returned the user would be able to click on it which they are not allowed

Comment: When you use different filtering/sorting options, the button you wish to disable should be also different? It should be always last row in the table?

Comment: I have added an update with an example screenshot from my test data returned

Comment: Never thought about filtering.  The record i need to stop the user deleting is a record added by the company as default so the user shouldn't be allowed.  May be i need to find a way to add an `attribute to the last row then look for it and disable/remove it that way`

Comment: Looking at it there is no filter or sorting allowed in the `DataTable`, just `pagination` so yes it'll always be the last row returned in the the data

Comment: I've modified my code according to your feedback. Does it fulfill your needs now?

Comment: re: the user is NOT allowed to modify or delete this row whether there is 1 record or 100 record's.


are you talking about a specific data row that can't be deleted?  Because the row order is changeable (it looks like your table would be sortable), sorting on a field would let someone get around that limitation.

If it's a specific data row (say, id=1) then you can alter your render method to not render the delete button when id == 1.